# What is the difference between FOR LOGIN and FROM LOGIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When creating user based on login using SQL Server authentication, what is the difference between FOR LOGIN and FROM LOGIN in CREATE USER statement?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. You must use one or the other though.

The various examples on [MSDN for CREATE USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) show this.

Comment: It's OK, but why there are these two options? I'm interesting in some background behind this (maybe backward compatibility, standards, ect.)

Comment: @Ilya: I'e no idea. CREATE USER is new in SQL Server 2005, so no legacy. I don't know if security is covered by the ANSI standards

Comment: @Ilya: ANSI Standard covers only the CREATE/DROP ROLE and GRANT/REVOKE statements from security.